# Set PredicateBuilder also on child collection

Tags: c#, linq, predicatebuilder

I am trying to apply the predicate not only to the entity parent but also to the child collection. The following is part of my code:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Entity>();
foreach (string keyword in keywords)
{
    string temp = keyword;
    predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Name.Equals(temp));
    predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Addresses.Select(x=> x.Name.Equals(temp));
}
```

The line `predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Addresses.Select(x=> x.Name.Equals(temp));` is not working ? any ideas as to why?

**EDIT**

In the following demo I am asking to get entity parent and child with name = tom but I also get child name = tom2.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var result = GetAll(GetAll(), new List<string> { "tom" });
}

private static List<User> GetAll()
{
    return new List<User>
    {
        new User
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "tom",
            Addesses = new List<Addesses>
            {
                    new Addesses { Id = 1, Name = "tom" },
                    new Addesses { Id = 1, Name = "tom2" },
            }
        },
            new User
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "sam",
            Addesses = new List<Addesses>
            {
                    new Addesses { Id = 1, Name = "sam" },
                    new Addesses { Id = 1, Name = "sam2" },
            }
        },
    };
}

private static List<User> GetAll(List<User> users, List<string> keywords)
{
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<User>();

    foreach (string keyword in keywords)
    {
        string temp = keyword;
        predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Name.Equals(temp));
        predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Addesses.Any(x => x.Name.Equals(temp)));
    }

    var result = users
        .Where(predicate)
        .ToList();

    return result;
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Addesses> Addesses { get; set; }
}

public class Addesses
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `p.Addresses.Select(x=> x.Name.Equals(temp)` is not returning a boolean result.

Depending on your actual logic you may want to look into `Any`:

```
predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Addresses.Any(x=> x.Name.Equals(temp));
```

or `All`:

```
predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Addresses.All(x=> x.Name.Equals(temp));
```

Comment: Hey Aomine, your examples compile but I still getting all the child. I updated my question to show how I use the predicate. Thanks

Comment: @Dino you didn't actually explain what you wanted to accomplish. please elaborate on this; assuming you're using `Any` as suggested in my answer then when you perform `GetAllAsync())
                .Where(predicate)
                .ToList()` the predicate is saying "if there's any Entity who's name is exactly equal to any of the strings in the `keywords` sequence then retain it **or** if the Entities addresses name is exactly equal to any of the strings in the `keywords` sequence then retain it".

Comment: @Dino I've simply given an example above as to how you can solve the compilation error but you'll need to alter the logic to fit your needs or criteria (and I don't know what that is).

Comment: As an aside (something you may want to look into in the future), you could avoid the `PredicateBuilder` entirely and instead create a `HashSet<string>` containing the `keywords` and then in the `Where` clause, you could simply do `.Where(e => theHashSetIdentifier.Contains(e.Name) || e.Addresses.Any(a => theHashSetIdentifier.Contains(a.Name))`  etc..

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, I am going to make a simple example of what I want to achieve.